# Get number of results for Google Search Appliance query

Tags: google-search-appliance

We are trying to implement a feature on our search results page similar to dynamic navigation, but different enough that the included dynamic navigation feature cannot be used to meet our business requirements. We've got everything working the way we need, except for one thing.

Using "RES/M" will display the number of results for the current search, but we need the number for a different search, so that we could display that number before the user was to try that search, very similar to dynamic navigation, and if the number is 0, to not enable that other search.

For Example:

```
Current Search (234)
Search 2 (2)
Search 3 (67)
Search 4 (0)
```

Is there any way to get the number of results for a search other than the search that's being run at the time?

Comment: You probably have to execute 3 searches...  Possibly doable with JavaScrips.  Are you using an XSLT stylehseet to generate your front end?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the only way to do this, is to put in your frontend one ajax call for each additional search that you need.
This is not a clean solution, but the only that I know: for one of our customer we have implemented a similar solution using JQuery and it works very well.

Be careful about the number of ajax parallel request you do, because GSA has a maximum number of concurrent request that can handle depending on the version.

In the end, if you want an accurate result for each additional search, you can use the parameter rc=1, see here (Appendix A: Estimated vs. Actual Number of Results): http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/www.google.com/it//support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/70/gsa_doc_set/xml_reference/xml_reference.pdf. But be careful because this parameter can introduce high latency to the search.

Regards